# How is this a permutation test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, interpretation, permutation-test

I am trying to read a research paper ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.13616)) that involves a permutation test. My (limited) understanding of a permutation test is that you get two samples of data, compute a statistic based on both samples, then compute the same statistic based on many permutations of the gathered data and calculate the proportion that were greater than the observed value.

The permutation test in this paper concerns quantiles. The test seems to be that $B$ times, some data are gathered and each time $k = 1, \dots, B$ we do this, we calculate a quantile $A_k$ for each data set gathered. Then we calculate the proportion of these quantiles $A_1, \dots, A_B$ that were less than some reference quantile $A_0$, which was calculated from some reference set of data. This proportion is our $p$-value, so we reject the null when most of the quantiles $A_1, \dots, A_B$ are bigger than the reference quantile $A_0$.

**Question:** Can somebody explain to me how what I've described above is a permutation test? I don't see any permuting going on. And I don't even understand the rejection criteria. If you assume the $B$ datasets should be similar to the reference data set, then shouldn't many of the numbers $A_1, \dots, A_B$ be *close* to $A_0$? And you'd reject when many of them are far away from $A_0$? The test as constructed would not reject when all of $A_1, \dots, A_B$ are less than $A_0$, but isn't that actually evidence that the two distributions are different?

I am putting screenshots of the relevant parts of the paper below, but I realize there is a lot of jargon, so I've tried above to explain the gist of what's going on above.

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. "My (limited) understanding of a permutation test is that you get two samples of data" --  permutation tests might involve something other than two samples. Some may have one sample some might have three or 12 or some other number."  2. "compute the same statistic based on many permutations of the gathered data"; well, yes, but the 'permutations' are not always explicitly of observations between samples. You need to identify some exchangeable quantity (depending on what you're testing and what you assume under the null) and those things are exchanged ... ctd

Comment: ctd ...  e.g. in a signed rank test the signs of observations are reallocated to the ranks.